# javascript 2 popup windows in one document

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

i try to use [This code](http://jsfiddle.net/p7NbX/15/).
It works good with 1 window, but i need 2 popup window.

i try to modified it like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    PopUpHide();
});
function PopUpShow(){
    $("#popup1").show();
    $("#popup2").show();
}
function PopUpHide(){
    $("#popup1").hide();
    $("#popup2").hide();
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="b-container">
    Sample Text
    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()">Show popup</a>
</div>
<div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Text in Popup
    <a href="javascript:PopUpHide()">Hide popup</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="b-container">
    Sample Text
    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()">Show popup</a>
</div>
<div class="b-popup" id="popup2">
    <div class="b-popup-content">
        Text in Popup
    <a href="javascript:PopUpHide()">Hide popup</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where i make mistake?

Comment: what does it do? how is that wrong? what do you want it to do?

Comment: Code from link. when you press "show popup" open window with text "text in popup". I need 2 link when you pres first you get "text1", when you press second you get text "text2"

Answer (score 1):

You're most probably showing two popups above each others, give one of them different position and class and use different Javascript function to show each, or send a variable to the function to decide which one to view.

Would be something like that:

```
function popupshow(whichOne)
{
    if(whichOne == 'first'){
        $("#popup1").show();
        $("#popup2").hide();
    }
    else{
        $("#popup1").hide();
        $("#popup2").show();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: here's the fiddle code as you requested. http://jsfiddle.net/jBf2y/2/

Comment: when i use your code get that them both open when i open my page.`<script type= text/javascript>
$(document).ready(function(){
    PopUpHide();
});
function PopUpShow(whichOne)
{
    if(whichOne == 'first'){
        $("#popup1").show();
        $("#popup2").hide();
    }
    else{
        $("#popup1").hide();
        $("#popup2").show();
    }
}
</script> `

Answer (score 0):

Your code above is working. You just need to set a margin to #popup2 div. 
They bot appear together, but as they are in the same position, you only see one of them.

Comment: so i should make <div class="b-container2">
    Sample Text
    <a href="javascript:PopUpShow()">Show popup2</a>
</div>
<div class="b-popup" id="popup2">
    <div class="b-popup-conten2t">
        Text in Popup2
    <a href="javascript:PopUpHide()">Hide popup</a>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: just set the margin-top of #popup2 to 100px and you will see it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    PopUpHide();
});
function PopUpShow1(){
    $("#popup1").show();
function PopUpShow2(){
    $("#popup2").show();
}
function PopUpHide(){
    $("#popup1").hide();
    $("#popup2").hide();
}
```

In the end i make like this